# Run test suite verbosely, but exclude logs

Tags: go

I am developing a package which uses the `log` package and logs a variety of things.

I would like to run `go test -v ./...` on my package and output the list of tests that pass/fail *without* the `log`s that are being used. This is helpful to me in the fact that I can get an overview of my entire test suite, without being cluttered by test-specific output.

In the docs for `go help testflag`, it says:

```
    -v
        Verbose output: log all tests as they are run. Also print all
        text from Log and Logf calls even if the test succeeds.
```

Is there a way to separate these two functionalities, and set `go test` to `log all tests as they are run` without `print(ing) all text from Log and Logf calls even if the test succeeds`?

Comment: No you can't separate the two, but the `-v` options is referring to `Log` and `Logf` calls in the testing package. It can't control what you do with the `log` package.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an example output, so I cannot give a `code` answer. But if you are on a `Unix` machine, you can use `go test -v ./... | grep <your_patter_of_interest>` to extract output lines with a certain pattern.

A simple example with example output adapted from [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Testing):

*Raw Output:*

```
$ go test

ok      github.com/user/stringutil        0.165s
ok      github.com/your/important/package 0.918s
log: passed a certain milestone
log: my code is great!
ok      github.com/another/great/package  0.124s
warning: hey there!
```

*Filtered Output:*

```
$ go test | grep "ok"

ok      github.com/user/stringutil        0.165s
ok      github.com/your/important/package 0.918s
ok      github.com/another/great/package  0.124s
```